# How to remove @license comments from source during npm build (will add manually)?

Tags: reactjs, vite, minify, bundling-and-minification, preact

I am developing a Vite-React webapp to be used by me only, and heres my simple build command in **package.json**: `"build": "vite build --emptyOutDir --base=./"`.

It uses the Google Firebase libraries that contains several submodules wherein each has the exact same @license comment leading to 48 times the **same repeated text contributing to 80% of my build** since everything else I have gzipped anyway.
Now I have no issue with **manually**, thankfully, and carefully adding all unique licenses wherever appropriate, but at first I wish to remove licenses during the build.

I realize the "@license" is probably the marker the minifier looks for, and I searched around but could not find a way to turn it off.
Please advise. And Thanks!

Comment: Strip comments in your build? I don't know why anyone would need comments in the build since it's all minified and/or obfuscated. Source maps don't have to be inline either.

Comment: @kelsny exactly! and still license comments **do** exist in the build if the build tool finds a comment prefixed with "@license" and thereafter skips such comments from minification, Its not obfuscated, and I just wish to remove the duplicates, thats all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default minifier now is `esbuild` (https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-minify).

Here is the new config that works:

```
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  build: {
    // ...
  },
  esbuild: { legalComments: 'none' },
})
```

https://esbuild.github.io/api/#legal-comments

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure `terser` through your `vite.config.js`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    terserOptions: {
      format: {
        comments: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

> `comments` (default `"some"`) -- by default it keeps JSDoc-style comments that contain "@license", "@copyright", "@preserve" or start with `!`, pass `true` or `"all"` to preserve all comments, `false` to omit comments in the output, a regular expression string (e.g. `/^!/`) or a function.

[Terser's Docs](https://terser.org/docs/options/#format-options)

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction. During build I found that Terser is no longer default build tool, and so I will have to configure esbuild instead.

Comment: So I didnt find any esbuild config options that Vite exposes in its settings, nor any other easy way, and also Terser is listed to be a better minifier, so I installed that. thx

Comment: Does this still work? My comments are not removed. In fact nearly all options are totally ignored. I made sure to add `minify: 'terser'`