# How to remove licence comment in JS for development with Vite?

Tags: javascript, typescript, comments, vite, minify

Strangely, Vite takes 4 seconds to transform my short code! That is tedious when making many changes to typescript files, and having to wait that long. Furthermore, I found that one of my short files weighs 560KB and has 4,000 lines after minification! Is this delaying Vite transformation?

I found out that the file was such big due to a licence. Is it possible to remove licence comments for development transformation?

Comment: Could the [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173608/how-to-remove-license-comments-from-source-during-npm-build-will-add-manually) possibly help?

Comment: @PaulT. I tried both configs in the answers, and none of them worked.